# R Markdown/Flexdashboard

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I have created a basic flexdashboard (used few plotly objects as well) and trying to share it with a colleague of mine in an email, I have saved it(file.html) to my desktop but when I open it, I cannot see the plots. In the bottom left corner of the file.html I see
"file failed to load /extensions/mathzoom.js"

Any help?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689924/mathjax-file-failed-to-load-extensions-mathzoom-js

Answer (score 0):

Are you knowningly trying to use `mathzoom.js`? might suggest updating your R, Rstudio, Rmarkdown package, flexdashboard package, and plotly package to remove this error. What if you re-render the flexdashboard, but with a few added YAML lines to help keep the file self contained, hopefully eliminating the mathzoom.js error

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
  self_contained: yes
  mode: selfcontained
---
```